# Uniqueify returning a empty list

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to  make a  function Uniqueify(L)  that will be given either a list of numbers or a list of strings (non-empty), and will return a list of the unique elements of that list. 
So far I have:

```
def Uniquefy(x):
    a = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] in a == False:
            a.append(x[i])
    return a
```

It looks like the `if str(x[i]) in a == False:` is failing, and that's causing the function to return a empty list. 
Any help you guys can provide?

Answer (score 4):

Relational operators all have exactly the same precedence and are chained. This means that this line:

> ```
> if x[i] in a == False:
> ```

is evaluated as follows:

> ```
> if (x[i] in a) and (a == False):
> ```

This is obviously not what you want.

The solution is to remove the second relational operator:

```
if x[i] not in a:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) based on the list which will only contain unique values:

```
>>> s = ["a", "b", "a"]
>>> print set(s)
set(['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The best option here is to use a set instead! By definition, sets only contain unique items and putting the same item in twice will not result in two copies.

If you need to create it from a list and need a list back, try this. However, if there's not a specific reason you NEED a list, then just pass around a set instead (that would be the duck-typing way anyway).

```
def uniquefy(x):
   return list(set(x))
```

Comment: This will change the order of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in `set` type to get unique elements from a collection:

```
x = [1,2,3,3]
unique_elements = set(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) here. It reduces the `in` operation time:

```
def Uniquefy(x):
    a = set()
    for item in x:
        if item not in a:
            a.add(item)
    return list(a)
```

Or equivalently:

```
def Uniquefy(x):
    return list(set(x))
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use a set in the first example, as you are already checking that the item doesn't exist. (`if item not in a:`)

Comment: @vishen the `in` operation used on `list` is much slower when compared to it's usage on `set`. That's why I replaced `list` with `set` in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

If order matters:

```
def uniquefy(x):
    s = set()
    return [i for i in x if i not in s and s.add(i) is None]
```

Else:

```
def uniquefy(x):
    return list(set(x))
```